# How do i actually create/run this class? python

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a game where you fly arround galaxy and there should be thse other ships just flying somewhere but how can i actually run this? let's say like **X** ammount of times.

All so when is there any way to shutdown all ships?

```
class spaceship(): ###thigs that fly arround when GUI == 4

    def __init__(self,GUIstatus):

        self.shipUp = pygame.image.load("icons/shipUP.png")
        self.shipRight = pygame.image.load("icons/shipRIGHT.png")
        self.shipLeft = pygame.image.load("icons/shipLEFT.png")
        self.shipDown = pygame.image.load("icons/shipDOWN.png")
        self.shipImage = self.shipLeft
        self.shipnpc_x = 0
        self.shipnpc_y = 0
        self.GUIstatus = GUIstatus

        self.shipType = (random.randrange(0,10))
        self.randomspeed = (random.randrange(0,5))
        self.speed = 10 += self.randomspeed

        self.exists = 0

        ##Logic place for selecting and randomizing ship and things

    def Update(self):
            if self.exists == 1:
                return
            if self.exists == 0 and self.GUIstatus == 4:
                if dirrection == LEFT:
                    self.shipnpc_x +=selfspeed
                    self.shipImage = self.shipLeft

                if dirrection == RIGHT:
                    self.shipnpc_x -=selfspeed
                    self.shipImage = self.shipRight

                if dirrection == UP:
                    self.shipnpc_y -=self.speed
                    self.shipImage = self.shipUp

                if dirrection == DOWN:
                    self.npcship_y +=self.speed
                    self.shipImage = self.shipDown


    def Draw(self,screen):
            if  self.exists == 1:
                return
            screen.blit(self.shipImage,(self.shipnpc_x,self.shipnpc_y))
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. You can create new instances by `ship1 = spaceship()` and then call the update/draw method using `ship1.Draw()` or `ship1.Update()`. But I'm guessing that's not what you mean? Also, it's conventional to name class names `Spaceship` _(CamelCase)_ and methods/variables `update` _(lower_case)_ . This convention makes it easier for other programmers to understand each others programs.

Comment: you need `mainloop` in which you move all ships in every loop. Every ship should have own method `update()` which change its position.

Comment: [simple example](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/follow-player) where you have player and two mosters - when you move player then mosters move too.

Comment: Yes sorry for being bit unclear 
How can i like create 30 ships at a time without every time saying that ship1 = spaceship()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, this is actually a quite common problem that beginners face.

What you want to do is to put your objects in some kind of list (in python, you usually use `[]`), and instead of calling methods on a single object, like

```
ship1.Update()
```

you use a loop to iterate over that list, like

```
for ship in ships:
    ship.Update()
```

But since you're using pygame, it's even easier, since there a classes that will do some of the heavy lifting for you.

You should start by using the [`Sprite`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and [`Group`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) class, so let's change your `spaceship` class. Note the comments

```
class Spaceship(pygame.sprite.Sprite): ###thigs that fly arround when GUI == 4

    def __init__(self, ships, GUIstatus):

        # ships is a Group for all ships 
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, ships)
        self.shipUp = ...

        # the image has to be in self.image
        self.image = self.shipLeft

        # no need for shipnpc_x and shipnpc_y, since we store
        # our position in self.rect
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.GUIstatus = GUIstatus

        self.shipType = ...

    # this has to be called update instead of update
    # to work with groups
    def update(self):

        # to change the position, we just alter self.rect

        if self.exists == 0 and self.GUIstatus == 4:
            if dirrection == LEFT:
                self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
                self.shipImage = self.shipLeft

            if dirrection == RIGHT:
                self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)
                self.shipImage = self.shipRight

            if dirrection == UP:
                self.rect.move_ip(0, -self.speed)
                self.shipImage = self.shipUp

            if dirrection == DOWN:
                self.rect.move_ip(0, self.speed)
                self.shipImage = self.shipDown

    # no need for the Draw function, since it's handled
    # by the sprite class' draw function
```

Now with these changes in place, we just have to create a [`Group`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group):

```
ships = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

So whenever you create a Spaceship, you put it into the ships group by just passing the group to the initializer. If you want 30 ships, just use a loop:

```
for _ in xrange(30):
    Spaceship(ships, GUIstatus)
```

As for updating and drawing, just call

```
ships.update()
ships.draw(screen)
```

in your main loop, and the `Group` class takes care to call `update` and `draw` on each `Sprite` inside it (basically it just iterates over a list with a `for` like I've written above).

That's it! If you want to get rid of an `Spaceship`, just either call the [`kill`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill) function on it (probably inside the update method), or use something like [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) to have it done automatically.

In the end, you probably want to have multiple groups, e.g. one group for everything that you call `update` and `draw` on in your mainloop, and, if you create let's say a shooter game, one group for all enemies and one for your bullets, so you can use [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) for collision detection etc...

Comment: 'self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)' inside of are (x,y) right?
and what should xrange be?